# Converting Query from DB2 to PostgreSQL, Now takes hours to run

Tags: performance, db2, postgresql-13

I have a project for converting some web pages from using DB2 to the same data/tables/etc within PostgreSQL. I'm running into an issue where a query that would normally run in less than a second for 30,000 rows on DB2 is taking hours on PostgreSQL.

The query is similar to:

```
select (
    select sum(b.numfield)
    from tableone a
    join tabletwo b
        on a.oneid = b.twoid
    where c.custno = a.custno
)
from tablethree c
```

The actual query that I'm trying to convert is much larger, but through debugging I found this to be the simplest example.

I just finished running the query on the PostgreSQL server, and after spinning on "Waiting for the query to complete..." for ~4 hours, it finally returned the rows. On the other hand, it returns all 30,185 rows in DB2 almost immediately (And they returned the same data).

The subselect is necessary only because in the actual query, 'tablethree' will be getting updated. It is a statement that updates a cube-table with current numeric values. It is a large and complex table, and is probably unnecessary since this query also reproduces the problem in the exact same way. Another way of writing it, but harder to test without creating test tables, would be

```
update tablethree c
set mynum = (
    select sum(b.numfield)
    from tableone a
    join tabletwo b
        on a.oneid = b.twoid
    where c.custno = a.custno
)
where ...
```

Either way you look at it, the first query I posted should not have such a significant difference in runtimes in my eyes.

Is there some optimization happening behind the scenes for DB2 that I need to implement in PostgreSQL? Is there any way to view if it is still working on the query in pgAdmin without doing an "Explain" since I haven't even been able to run it once successfully? What else am I doing wrong?

Comment: Without more context this is really hard to tell how to rewrite the query. Most probably rewriting the scalar sub-query to a lateral join might be one option

Comment: Right... The issue comes in because the subquery is necessary. 'tablethree' in this case is actually being updated in the real query, a patch-job to fix a cube that the one who wrote it accidently made necessary. But, in any case, such a simple and small table shouldn't be taking literal hours, no?

Comment: Please consider reading [this advice](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3034/asking-query-performance-questions). Might be useful to provide the plans for both Db2 and Postgres

Comment: Have you tried rewriting it into a proper join instead of a subselect?

Comment: @mustaccio I am doing a proper analyze now, but it will take a while. I will most likely be able to update it with the runtime information tomorrow. Thank you for that link though, useful information.

Comment: Do you have any indexes on any of the columns? Also, just doing EXPLAIN (without ANALYZE) can often give you enough of an idea why a query takes a long time to finish, and it would be much faster than using EXPLAIN ANALYZE if the actual query takes a long time to finish.

Comment: So explain analyze did finish, but is not helpful at all. Something else is definitely wrong. The query plan json is just a begin bracket '[' and even the graphical analysis and statistics are missing their runtime information so I can't even pinpoint where the bottleneck is coming in. There's not a whole lot to post.

Answer (score 1):

Postgres offers an extension to the UPDATE syntax that allows to specify a FROM clause. This is typically faster than a co-related subquery as derived table in the FROM clause is evaluated once, rather than over and over again.

So the UPDATE statement is very likely to be faster if you use:

```
update tablethree c
  set mynum = t.mysum
from (
    select a.custno, sum(b.numfield) as mysum
    from tableone a
      join tabletwo b on a.oneid = b.twoid
    group by a.custno
) t
where c.custno = t.custno
  and ... other conditions ...
```

Comment: Interesting. I'll be implementing it into the actual update query soon, but I changed the select query to a similar way as this and it worked (basically select mysum from tablethree join subselect on custno etc etc). Is there any specific reason a normal subselect like I originally had would take so much longer? I'm assuming DB2's optimizer will automatically switch the query to something like this, and that's why it was so much quicker, but it would be nice to know for sure for the future.